# MongoDB: how to find and return all documents with the field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB, I have a collection like this.

Now what I want is that to return all the record that has "key" in "data" field. and I need to count how many of them.

How can I do that? any help is appreciated.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b306801a1eab22e79701e53"), 
"data" : { 
           "Key" : [ [ "1529899007", "KeyIn" ] ] 
         }, 
"devicecode" : "MMG5S000001177AFP0069@Timi"

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b3066aca1eab22e48cc2cc7"), 
  "data" : { "Quick" : [ [ "1529898664", "15", "https://www.partner.outlook.cn/owa/?targetname=mail.dentons.cn" ] ] }, 
"devicecode" : "MP194YHF@LENOVO" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b306824a1eab22e77858c88"), 
"data" : { "Key" : [ [ "1529587723", "KeyIn" ], 
                     [ "1529587723", "Num" ], 
                     [ "1529667745", "KeyIn" ]
"devicecode" : "MP1D1XAH@LENOVO" }
```

Comment: One more question:  How can I count all the records that have "key in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:

```
db.col.count({ "data.Key": { $exists: true } })
```

EDIT: use [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) with [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) to search for `KeyIn`

```
db.col.count({
    $expr: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
            $map: {
                input: "$data.Key",
                in: { $in: [ "KeyIn", "$$this" ] }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. one more question. how can I count all the records that have "key in"?

Comment: I used the format you said. but return 0 for "KeyIn"